# Node Js high frequency file write

Tags: node.js, monaco-editor

I have a large array of objects (100000 records) containing text buffer and position of insertion.
Wondering is there any efficient way to insert those buffers at specified posiotion into an existing file?

Comment: why don't you use the database ?

Comment: In frontend I have Moncao Editor which open a large file sent from server. When user updates the content in the editor, moncao editor gives exactly what changed and which place. I can use the same info in backend node server to modify the file. So I don't have to pass the whole file again to server. I was trying fs.open and fs.write to write the buffer at specif position in file. But it seems inefficient.